# how to create a static page with wordpress header and footer?

Tags: wordpress

how to create a static page with wordpress header and footer? I am not talking about static homepage just a static page using only wordpress header and footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates!

Create a blank .php file called whatever in your theme folder, put in the following at top:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: My very own template!
* Description: Look pah! I made a template!
*/ 
get_header();
?>
Whatevercontent you want the page to have, could get content from the wp_editor like this:
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Create a new page in the admin area, check your right for "Page Attributes", in there you will find a "Template" dropdown, chose your own template here "My very own template!" it would be called in this situation.

Now that page will load the php code in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if it helps :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/header-footer/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates